# One time stripe payment webpage wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

Is there a way to easily have a payment webpage that can be used only one time. Here is the scenario :

1. I sell my product by phone for example 20$
2. I generate a webpage for this 20$ payment
3. I send the URL to the client.
4. He pays the product
5. I send the product

Etc... for other clients, the amount needs to be easily customisable.

It would be great if the payment doesn't need to create an account on my website. For information I am using wordpress on my website so if any plugin can make it easily it would be greet

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout), it seems to cover all your use cases.